# CoreData: cannot lightweight migrate deletion of entity 'no such table'

Tags: core-data, ios7, core-data-migration

I am trying to migrate two Core Data models through lightweight migration. The differences are only, that I removed a bunch of entities in the newer model as they are not needed anymore.

When running my application, upon launch, I get the following error message:

```
CoreData: error: (1) I/O error for database at /var/mobile/Applications/E117D13D-C4DE-4F70-BBDB-F3F4E36A6A86/Documents/.Database.sqlite.migrationdestination_41b5a6b5c6e848c462a8480cd24caef3.  SQLite error code:1, 'no such table: ZFLIGHTSTATUSSEARCH'
```

`FlightStatusSearch` is one of the entities I dropped. I am pretty sure I have deleted entities a couple of times and lightweight migration worked like a charm. I have no clue what I could do wrong here as it is the same core data implementation I have used in this app for a couple of years now, without any problems. I am running on iOS7.

The error message is triggered a couple of times during launch. As far as I can tell, this happens every time I am trying to interact with the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.

Has anybody experienced a similar issue or knows what this error is trying to tell me?

**UPDATE:**

The first of this error logs occurs when calling `-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:URL:options:error:]`

The store type is `SQLite`, the configuration is `Main`, which is the name of my main configuration that is used around the app, the URL refers to the old, not yet migrated database and options is this:

```
NSDictionary* optionsDictionary = @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: @YES,
                                    NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: @YES};
```

The model that is used when instantiating the coordinator **does not** contain the `FlightStatusSearch` model, the error message is referring to.

**UPDATE 2**

This is the stack trace:

```
#0  0x389c16a0 in objc_exception_throw ()
#1  0x2e4178aa in -[NSSQLiteConnection prepareSQLStatement:] ()
#2  0x2e4d0c08 in -[NSSQLConnection prepareAndExecuteSQLStatement:] ()
#3  0x2e50c66e in -[_NSSQLiteStoreMigrator performMigration:] ()
#4  0x2e505fa4 in -[NSSQLiteInPlaceMigrationManager migrateStoreFromURL:type:options:withMappingModel:toDestinationURL:destinationType:destinationOptions:error:] ()
#5  0x2e4bcb96 in -[NSMigrationManager migrateStoreFromURL:type:options:withMappingModel:toDestinationURL:destinationType:destinationOptions:error:] ()
#6  0x2e4fe3f0 in -[NSStoreMigrationPolicy(InternalMethods) migrateStoreAtURL:toURL:storeType:options:withManager:error:] ()
#7  0x2e4fd6f8 in -[NSStoreMigrationPolicy migrateStoreAtURL:withManager:metadata:options:error:] ()
#8  0x2e4fec5e in -[NSStoreMigrationPolicy(InternalMethods) _gatherDataAndPerformMigration:] ()
#9  0x2e40b0ba in -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:] ()
#10 0x001dca70 in -[CoreDataManager persistentStoreCoordinator] at /Users/michael/Projects/12_IP_MyProject/Components/CoreData/CoreDataManager.m:160
#11 0x000afed0 in -[AppDelegate init] at /Users/michael/Projects/12_IP_MyProject/MyProject/Classes/AppDelegate.m:86
#12 0x30eb2190 in UIApplicationMain ()
#13 0x000af9d4 in main at /Users/michael/Projects/12_IP_MyProject/MyProject/Supporting Files/main.m:16
#14 0x38ebaab6 in start ()
```

Best regards,
Michael

Comment: Was the database originally created by Core Data?

Comment: Is it possible that the migration finished, but then you’re somehow trying to access the new store with the old model? On calling which methods exactly does the error occur?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've updated my question. @eofster Yes, this database was created by CoreData on first launch of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out.

I forgot to drop one entity with the following environment:

Class A inherits from Class B, Class A represents the entity I forgot to drop, Class B has been a Core Data entity but was converted to a non-coredata model. Now there was an entity that inherited from a non-coredata model. This results in the error message I mentioned above. The table that is mentioned there was the table from Class B, which has been an entity, but isn't anymore. As soon as I dropped Class A from the model, too, everything worked.

Thanks for your help.